# Como colocar site online através de domínio?

Tags: php, apache, hospedagem

Olá pessoal estou tentando colocar um site online através de um domínio que já criei,ele já me deu configurações prontas do FTP com uma pasta para eu poder dar upload nos arquivos que eu quiser.
O problema é que quando eu tento acessar os arquivos da pasta em que eu coloquei,ele da os seguintes erros :

**404 Not Found :**

The requested URL /localizazao.html was not found on this server.

**403 Forbidden :**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Gostaria de saber como resolver este problema,para poder colocar online o meu site.
A pasta que eu estou acessando esta chamada como public_html dentro dela esta meus arquivos para eu acessar.
Caso precisarem de mais informações para tentar sanar meu problema eu irei atentamente postar logs mais específicos do problema.

**PHP versão : 5.2**

**Apache versão : 2.2.19**

Comment: "localizazao"? é isso mesmo?

Comment: Nome do arquivo html.

Comment: está salvo exatamente com esta mesma grafia? e está tudo em minúsculas?

Comment: Sim,está salvo conforme da onde eu estou puxando o arquivo para lá.

Comment: Se não atrapalhar em nada, ponha o domínio aqui nos comentários, pra gente testar, e depois vc deleta. Salve também uma página `index.html`, com algum conteudo diferente desta dentro da pasta, para testarmos.

Comment: O domínio está como : 7soft.com.br.

Comment: ponha o index.html lá na hospedagem, dentro do public_html, e verifique se está tudo com permissão de leitura.

Comment: Sim,já fiz isto,o index.html está dentro do public_html,junto com outros arquivos,o problema é exatamente este,ele não deixa eu nem acessar o servidor,dando os erros 403 e 404

Comment: pode ser permissão errada nas pastas. O certo mesmo é você ver com quem configurou a hospedagem. Verifique se as pastas tem permissão de leitura para o usuário do Apache.

Comment: Estou usando hospedagem gratuita,já que este site é somente para meu Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso,mas a hospedagem que estou usando é boa,pensei o mesmo que você,deve ser erro nas permissões,agora aonde achar a permissão errada é o problema.

Comment: Infelizmente, por mais que a gente queira ajudar, acho que fica um pouco fora do escopo do site. Seria legal você ver alguém que conhece desse tipo de configuração que conseguisse te ajudar indo aí e vendo o problema real. Infelizmente pode ser tanta coisa diferente, que por aqui o máximo que dá é a gente ir chutando alternativas nos comentários.

Comment: Tudo bem amigo,mas obrigado por tentar me ajudar,vou tentar falar com outras pessoas que conheço que saibam mexer nessas configurações do Apache e do PHP. Mas mesmo assim obrigado pela atenção ao meu problema.

Comment: Se tiver algum progresso nas descobertas, avise.

Comment: Então amigo acabei por ver que aquele domínio 7soft.com.br eu só poderia usar se pagasse,ou seja,não tenho permissão para usar ele,testei outro domínio e funcionou. Obrigado por ter me respondido :)